# Variable does not exist in current context although it does exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm running unittests for a dll.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    List<MyObject> a = GetData();
}
```

That works fine BUT when I tried to change it to the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    List<MyObject> b = GetData();
    List<MyObject> a = GetData();
}
```

I got the problem that when I reach the breakpoint on b or a it says b is not existing in the current context. BUT the same line works for a collegue of mine.

I already restarted visual studio and cleaned the solution and rebuilt it.
Does anyone have an idea there?

Comment: Do both methods, `getData` and `GetData` exist? If so, what is the point?

Comment: corrected the typing error. Yes GetData exists. The code works fine without throwing an exception BUT when I try to debug it I get "variable out of context" message in the watch when I try to see what value b has and same problem when I move my mouse over b. Thus I can't see what value b has (the above is a reproduction of the problem but in the real code I NEED to know which value b has as that unittest has a problem I try to identify)

Comment: Maybe you are in release mode and `b` has been optimized away? I guess it would make more sense to post your actual unit test.

Comment: @nvoigt that was it (release mode). tnx.  completely overlooked that!

Comment: And on a more personal note: take your unit test's code and copy it over to ConsoleApplication1 and debug it there. I've had so many wierd things happening while debugging in unit tests, that I gave it up. If a test fails and I need to debug, I copy it to a real project and debug it there.

Comment: Interesting will keep that in mind tnx (so far that phenomenon was the first thing that was strange....aside from a test working that by all means SHOULD have failed but that is what I tried to look into with b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you are debugging a version compiled in release mode / with the 'Optimise Code' flag set.

This is because the compiler is then free to take variables out of scope if it knows they can never be used, where as Debug mode will retain variables in scope as long as they are in-scope from a language perspective.

Since b (and a) are never used in you code the compiler is free, in release mode to treat your code as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    GetData();
    GetData();
}
```

Which indeed it does.